# How can I share my Google Chrome bookmarks with others online?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, chrome-bookmarks

I would like to create a shared collection of my Google Chrome bookmarks on a certain topic to let other users access it online.

Answer (score 3):

You can save them into a file and share that file. That is not too convenient, and needs to be repeated periodically, but probably the only acceptable way.

You could also share your Google ID and password, so they can all log in to it. That is not recommendable though - they would all be able to change the bookmarks, *and* you are sharing all other Google pieces. You could make an ID just for that, but they still could all edit.

You could develop (or find) an add-on or extension that allows that. I didn't find one, but with a gazillion out there, there might be one that can do it.